# Don't show all names on r barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

Well since I'm new here I can't post the image that would make this a whole lot easier.

Essentially, I have 45 pairs of bars in a barplot. Each group of 5 pairs belongs to a different city. What I want to do is only show one name for each group of 5 and not show any repeats.

The code I have so far is:

```
barplot(matrix(c(sixth_shop, thirteenth_shop), nrow=2, ncol=45, byrow=T),
        beside=T, legend.text=c('6th Shoppers', '13th Shoppers'), ylim = c(0, 11000),
        col = c('light green', 'navy'), ylab = 'Number of Shoppers', main = 'Total Shoppers',
        names.arg = raw_data$Location)
```

Currently, R will either only show 8 of the 9 names or it will start repeating some of them and it looks very uneven. Is there a way to tell it to only show every 5th name?

Simple version:

If I have something like this:

```
barplot(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2), names.arg = c('cow', 'horse', 'pig', 'raccoon', 'butterfly'))
```

Can I make a barplot that looks like:

```
|
|
|          X
|       X  X
|    X  X  X  X
|_X__X__X__X__X_
       pig
```

Comment: Complaints about not being able to post images don't really absolve you of the responsibility of posting an example. Not does it mean you don't need to describe _clearly_ how these One name/five are supposed to appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just separate the plotting the the labeling.

```
barpos <- barplot(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2))
axis(1, at=barpos[3], labels=("pig"))
```

The x value where each bar is drawn is returned from `barplot`.

[image: Look what I can do!]

Comment: They are actually NOT at integer values, already in this plot you can see that the tickmark is slightly off the middle of the 3rd bar. This becomes more apparent if you add more bars and try to add a label to bars further to the right, e.g.:

mark=c(3,8,13);
cols=rep("grey", 15);
cols[mark]="red";
barplot(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2), 3), col=cols);
axis(1, at=mark, labels=c("pig","foo","bar"));

Comment: @bug313 True. I've updated the answer. It was wrong before.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick update @MrFlick, now it works great!